# Delete duplicate text within a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I've got cells in a column populated with data pulled from another tab using `A1= Results_ES!C1` and `A2= Results_ES!C2` etc.

Some of the data is duplicated whithin the cell, e.g.

Cell A1= `Black Black`

Cell A1 = `White White`

...and so on.
Basically, there's a line-break - ***`char(10)`*** - between each color so the first example (cell A1) in fact looks like this:

```
Black
Black
```

I'd like to keep only one appearance of each color, i.e., `A1= Black`
Ideally, I´d like the processing to happen automatically. In other words, I'd like to open the document and find it already corrected for me without having to manually run scripts.

I found some commands that might help such as ***LEFT, RIGHT, MID, TRIM, LEN, FIND, SEARCH, SUBSTITUTE, REPT***, etc., but they are generally used to work with two different cells, not within a single cell. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This worked on both your examples:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\w+")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep only the part until the linebreak with the following [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) command:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(Results_ES!C1, "^.*")
```

If you also want to remove any spaces in your text before the linebreak, add `TRIM`:

```
=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(Results_ES!C1, "^.*"))
```

Comment: Thnak you!! For the record, this is what I´ve done: =REGEXEXTRACT(Results_ES!S2, "^.*")

Comment: How would your formula deal with `Black Black` and `Black White`?

Comment: It wouldn't; I addressed only the sort of input actually stated by the OP, without guessing at what else their spreadsheet might contain.

Comment: @Jacob Jan Tuinstra - in this particular case I only have two pairs of the same word separated by a line break so 1999 answer does the job, but thank you for your observation

Comment: I've just received a new list of data to process but this time cells have duplicate content separated by a semicolon and a space like so: Black; Black | White; White. How could I modify the formula to obtain only one occurrence of Black and White?